# How can I create migration from existing database?

Tags: laravel, migration

How can I create migration from existing database?
I wanted to do this with `Xerton`. I try do execute:

```
php artisan make:migration
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
Not enough arguments (missing: "name").
```

Is it possible to migrate the existing database at once? Without having to migrate the tables separately?

Comment: make migration command is for creating new migration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a migration you have to specify the name of the migration like this :

```
php artisan make:migration create_users_table
php artisan make:migration add_votes_to_users_table
```

With Xerton :

Run php artisan migrate:generate to create migrations for all the table

Answer (score 1):

After you've correctly installed [Xethron](https://github.com/Xethron/migrations-generator) you could run this commands:

```
php artisan migrate:generate // to create migrations for all the tables
php artisan migrate:generate table1,table2,table3,table4,table5 // for specific tables
```

Comment: Is it possible to migrate the existing database at once? Without having to migrate the tables separately?

Comment: Yes, with the first command I posted: `php artisan migrate:generate`

Comment: I don't understand why you approved an aswer that is equal to mine but newest

Answer (score 0):

According to Xerton documentation you have to use `php artisan migrate:generate` command to generate migrations from existing database.

`php artisan make:migration [name]` is used to create new migration.