# Generating models from existing database at once

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm trying to generate models from an existing database at once without having to do it separately for all tables. I have tried to do this with `reliese/laravel`. I have executed:

```
php artisan -v code:models
```

However, I'm getting the following error.

> ErrorException  : mkdir(): Invalid path
>         at C:\xampp\htdocs\schaden\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem.php:466
>           462|         if ($force) {
>           463|             return @mkdir($path, $mode, $recursive);
>           464|         }
>           465|
>
> > 466|         return mkdir($path, $mode, $recursive);
> >             467|     }
> >             468|
> >             469|     /**
> >             470|      * Move a directory.
>
> Exception trace:
>     1   mkdir("")
>             C:\xampp\htdocs\schaden\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem.php:466

I'm not posting the full error stack here. Can anyone help?

Comment: You can use Xerton for this. Watch [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57198718/how-can-i-create-migration-from-existing-database/57199242#57199242) if you want

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best solution is using the package **Eloquent Model Generator** that you can find on github at https://github.com/krlove/eloquent-model-generator.

Then you can easily use, for example, `php artisan krlove:generate:model User --table-name=users` or `php artisan krlove:generate:model MyModel --table-name=my_models` and use some of the package options.

Comment: Is ithere anyway to do it at once for all tables? Thanks.

Comment: As far as I've tested that package no, it needs to be done model by model. Also a note to say that in my tests, I noticed some of the relations methods the package auto creates may not have the exact best return type. As an example I found `return $this->hasMany(Model::class)` where it should be a `$this->belongsToMany(Model::class)`. Give it a try using the `--backup` option ;)

Comment: for someone that not installed the eloquent model don't forget to `composer require krlove/eloquent-model-generator --dev`